# Unable to get contrast of image as described by its formula

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to get the contrast of an image using a formula but the contrast value is not exceeding 255. As well as whenever I tried to make some operation on my image matrix the element values also not exceeding 255. I tried converting the image matrix to double but the element values changed and are not equal to original pixel values.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
h = imread('C:\Users\LAXMIDHAR\Desktop\My proj files\abc.jpg');
g = rgb2gray(h);
% f = im2double(g);
[M,N] = size(g);
% 
% for i=1:M
%     for j=1:N
%         f(i,j) = f(i,j).*((i-j).^2);
%     end
% end
% 
% s = sum(sum(f));

s = 0;
for i = 1:M
    for j=1:N
        s = s+(g(i,j).*((i-j).^2));
    end
end

% s  is the contrast of image
```

`s` is expected to be large but its not exceeding 255. This is the contrast formula:

[image: Contrast formula]

Comment: Where did that equation come from? How does that equate to contrast? It looks strange to me.

Comment: In any case, your problem is that `g` is `uint8`, and therefore `s` is `uint8` also. MATLAB performs integer addition with saturation, meaning that surpassing 255 in the operation leads to 255 (rather than overflowing as it does in other languages). Simply convert your image to doubles first: `g = double(g)`.

Comment: Sir in that formula i and j are the coordinates and g(i,j) is the pixel value of image at i-th j-th location. Again as per your suggestion I tried converting to double but in that the values of pixel totally different when compared to original gray value of pixel.

Comment: Look at my suggestion again. If you use `im2double` then the values change, but I suggested you convert with `double`, which will not change the values.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind suggestion. Will you please help me with a formula for finding average contrast of an image?

Comment: I've seen contrast defined as `max(img)-min(img)`, but that is not very robust as the result depends on two pixels. You could think of using the standard deviation of the pixel values as a measure of contrast. Or the interquartile range.